# How to create a matrix containing pairwise ratio of two dataframes?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, correlation

I have two data-frames, one containing expression values of genes (n=2000) and another containing expression values of microRNA (n=350). I want to calculate the ratio of each microRNA with each gene and then visualize it.

Here is what I am doing:

I first created an empty data-frame

```
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 350, nrow = 2000))
```

The three data-frames are `m`, (2000, 350)  `control.mRNA` (2000, 1) and `control.miRNA` (350 , 1).

Now I am calculating their ratio with each other and filling the values into empty dataframe

```
for (i in 1:nrow(control.mRNA)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(control.miRNA)) {
    m[i,j] <- control.miRNA[j]/control.mRNA[i]
  }
}
```

But this is not working.
For multiplication there is function "crossprod" but I didn't find anything for division.

Comment: Convert to vectors and then use `outer(control.mRNA, control.miRNA, '/')`

Comment: If `control.mRNA` and `control.miRNA` are data-frames and not matrices, then you need to modify your code : `m[i,j] <- control.miRNA[j,1]/control.mRNA[i,1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `outer`. Here is a simpl(istic)e example:

```
u <- 1:5
v <- c(3,7)

outer(u, v, "/")
```

The result is a matrix with 5 (the # of coefs in `u`) rows and 2 (the # of coefs in `v`) columns with coefficients `u[i] / v[j]` in row `i` and col `j`. In order to have  `u[j] / v[i]` in row `i` and col `j`, you could then use `t`, the transposition operator:

```
M1 <- t(outer(u, v, "/"))
```

@shadow judiciously pointed out that `outer` takes vectors as arguments, and not matrices. This could easily be handled by converting the matrices to vectors first.

Let's take the same example as before, but with `U` and `V` two matrices instead of just vectors:

```
U <- matrix(1:5)
V <- matrix(c(3,7))
M2 <- t( outer(drop(U), drop(V), "/") )
```

Another solution is to transform `U` and `V` a little bit and use the matrix multiplication operator `%*%`:

```
M3 <- t( U %*% t(1/V) )
```